# Graph Toolkit React People Picker Error in console for User Photo Endpoint

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using Microsoft Graph Toolkit to add people picker to my REACT application. The people picker functionality is working but on the browser console it is logging error for the use photo API. Since the code behind the component is abstract, not sure what really is happening.Anybody faced this issue or any clue on why the error on console?

Error on console is below "HTTPMessageHandler.ts:31 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Otayeb@isdbdev.org/photo/$value 404 (Not Found)". As you can see it is trying to get the photo of the user from the graph endpoint and the dynamic value is not populated.

```
export default function NormalPP(){
Providers.globalProvider = new MsalProvider({
    clientId: '8a17f110-fe17-4594-9463-ffc39da24b9c'
  });
return(
    <div className="App">
        <header>
            <Login />
        </header>
        <PeoplePicker/>
    </div>

)
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you have set a photo for the user `Otayeb@isdbdev.org`? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-your-profile-photo-to-microsoft-365-2eaf93fd-b3f1-43b9-9cdc-bdcd548435b7 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-profile-azure-portal#to-add-or-change-profile-information.

Comment: And the user is O365/AAD account, not a guest account. Right?

Comment: Yes overlook from my side. Some of the users did not have the photo updated in their profile and hence go this error. Thank you @AllenWu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will be posted in the browser console if the user loaded to the people picker does not have their photo updated in their Office 365/Azure profile.